# Listing Running Processes and Sending Them to a File

Tags: bash, shell

my function is supposed to list all running processes and store them to process.id and if process.id exists, it should rename it to the current date with .id at the end of it, and then move it to the /logs directory. i think i have the mv and rename part working but it doesnt seem to save all of the processes to the file. do i have a syntax error on that part?

```
function processsaver()
{
if [ -r "process.id" ]; then
mv "process.id" logs/$(date +%d-%m-%y).id
ps -e > /process.id
fi
}
```

Comment: Great. What is your question?

Comment: Ideally you should have got permission denied error for accessing files under root `ps -e > /process.id`, if you are not running under root. Didn't you notice that

Answer (score 0):

`process.id` and `/process.id` are not the same path. You probably wanted `process.id` or `./process.id` in both places, since this kind of information *really* should not be in the filesystem root.